# Getting size and position of an SVG element relative to the view port using python

Tags: python, svg

I am trying to find the size and position of an SVG element relative to the view port using python even after applying transformations.

What I am looking for is similar to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) but in python(I am trying to add some svg elements to an existing svg)

So far the below svg modules I looked at don't seem to support this:

1. [pysvg](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysvg/0.2.2)
2. [svglib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svglib/)
3. [svgwrite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/svgwrite/)

**Update:[adding clarification requested in comment]**

This question is about getting the functionality of javascript function `object.getBoundingClientRect()` in python when working with svg. Any piece of python code that support this is acceptable)

Comment: @Person_who_down_Vote: Really appreciate if you could leave a reason for down vote so that I an improve the question. I am working with SVG for  the fist time.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thanks for clarification and I updated my question for clarity.  but I still do not understand how this question can lead to opinion based answers. My original question was about a python library that supports 'object.getBoundingClientRect()' function(which is supported in javascript). This cant be based on opinion, but have to be based on fact.(Whether the library support this functionality or not, that is a fact)

Comment: Who said it's opinion based? Some attempt at a solution would be nice of course... Personally I think it's probably too broad since you'd need to write code to measure the bounds every kind of element and then transform them all to the root document co-ordinate system.

Comment: @RobertLongson: Thanks for editing my question to suite SO. I was trying to avoid reinventing the wheel. I Know I can write custom code to resolve the specific issue I am facing. A library that supports all elements will be nice of course in case the scope of the problem changes along the way.